# How can i add search view to action bar in single activity with back arrow button not for all activity's?

Tags: android

i am navigating to members list Activity from drawer menu, here i need search view and back arrow button. when user clicks on search icon i want to expand it after completion of work he will navigate to back using arrow button. how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**1. create a search_layout like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/searchfield"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/custom_search_edit"
 android:hint="@string/search_hint"
 android:inputType="textFilter"
 android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
 android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
 android:textSize="15sp" />
```

**2. add this code in your activity**

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.search_layout);

     EditText search = (EditText) getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().
            findViewById(R.id.searchfield);

    search.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                      KeyEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(getSupportActionBar().DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | getSupportActionBar().DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**or you can use** [**Searchview**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)